# Apply Factory Pattern in two levels

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, factory-pattern

I want to ask if the use of the (abstract) `Factory Pattern` is recommendable in this case: I have 20 `Products` all of which are represented by a separate class which derives from a superclass `BaseProduct`. The `Products` are divided in 5 `Categories`, each one of which is also represented by a separate class which derives from a superclass `BaseCategory`. Each `Product` belongs ever to one specific `Category`. The creation of a `Product` is performed meaningfully and technically only in its `Category`, hence the respective `Category` must be instantiated just before the instantiation of the `Product`. However a `Category` cannot "stand alone" in the application without a `Product`. The selection of a `Product` to be created as well as the `Category` is determined by checking a `String`. To avoid a lot of `if-else` code in the client I prefer to use the `Factory Pattern` regarding the creation of Categories:

```
    class CategoryFactory{

       static Category createCategory(String s){

        if(s.equals("foo"))
            return new Category1();
        else if (s.equals("bar"))
            return new Category2();
        ...

         }
        }
```

My worry is how I tackle the creation of `Products` in each `Category`. Should I pass the `String` in the constructor of `Category` class and apply a similar `Factory` inside the Categories? Should I use `Factory` for `Products` and provide it as parameter in the constructor of `Category`? Is there a better approach for the whole problem? Keep in mind that I cannot create a `Product` after having the created the `Category`. When I instatiate a `Category` in the client, it must create and contain at the same time its `Product`.

Comment: Are you sure that a different class for each product and for each category is the right choice? It would help if you add the code for those two classes so we can see for what we are talking about.

Comment: They are widgets on a user interface and the widgets "Category" contain a widget "Product". How their code look like is irrelevant to the design, which my question concerns.

Comment: It is the design that I 've questioned, this is why I have asked for some code. From your example it seemed that your categories were marker classes i.e. I saw the empty constructors and I was wondering what was the functional-wise differences between two categories. If you are saying that you trust the design as it currently is then it is ok.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it that way.  It might be cleaner to have `Category` have a method called something like `getProductFactory()` at least this way if 2 `Categories` have similar or the same way to produce `Products` you could re-use the factory.